# Very weird SoapClient problem

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

```
 try
  {
    $client = new \SoapClient($wsdlUrl, array(
      'cache_wsdl' => 0, 'exceptions' => true, 'trace' => true));

    $client->getPage($parameter);
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
    die("exception");
  }
```

Okay this is what executes the SOAP request. $wsdlUrl holds the WSDLs URL and $parameter keeps an XML document.

**And everything works like a charm!**

Now I just add few more nodes to the XML document in $parameter and I get a fatal error.

This is not so weird necessarily, but what is weired is the combination of following three observations:

1) exceptions is set to true .... but no Exception is thrown / *this was b/c I forgot to place a backslash before Exception in the catch statement*.

2) instead an error is logged:

```
PHP Fatal error:  SoapClient::SoapClient(): 
'uri' option is required in nonWSDL mode in /var/w[...]
```

3) but the WSDL url is provided and of course valid, as *all works again just fine after skipping the adding of the new nodes*. they don't affect the wsdl parameter.

Comment: Just trying to help: "weird" is spelled, well, weirdly.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I tracked down the source of the problem. There is no satisfying answer really to that question but few things to learn! :)

The important thing is that the request has been sent and processed by the SOAP server.
But the server responds with an error.

So, obviously, even though a fatal error regarding no wsdl and no connection parameter is triggered *doesn't mean no request has been sent* - which is very counter logical in my opinion b/c if no wsdl is provided and no connection params as well, then how could the request be executed?

**EDIT**

There is another bug in the code. I forgot to place a backslash before Exception! Without it's not referring to the Exception class.

Then an exception is thrown and caught.